# How to check if puppet is configured correctly?

Tags: puppet

How can I check if my puppet set-up (one master, one agent on Ubuntu 14.04 ) is configured correctly? Is there some command to verify if everything is right?

Comment: not sure what you mean... it is a very vague question...

Comment: Which bit to you want to check? The master running, the agent running, the agents communication with the master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know, whether the puppet agent can connect to the puppet master and pull the configs. You can try running the agent in dry-run mode:

```
puppet agent -t --noop
```

For more details: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/man/agent.html

Note: You may need to sign the puppet agent cert on the master, if you don't have auto signing enabled.